# Closed form of a recurrence relation using generating functions.

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I was wondering if I could ask for your help with the following question. I get down to a certain point and get so lost I just can't progress and was wondering if I had made an obvious and horrendous mistake or if you had any pointers on where to go next.

***The Question:***

We have the recurrence relation

\begin{align*}
a_{n} & =2a_{n-1}-5a_{n-2}\\
\end{align*}

with the initial conditions

\begin{align*}
a_{0} & =0,a_{1}=1\\
\end{align*}

Find the closed form

***My (maybe poor) Attempt:***

Using $\underset{k\geq0}{f(x)=\sum}a_{k}x^{k}$ we get the following:

\begin{align*}
\underset{k\geq2}{\sum}a_{k} & =\underset{k\geq2}{\sum}2a_{k-1}x^{k}+\underset{k\geq2}{\sum}5a_{k-2}x^{k}\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
 & =\underset{1}{\underbrace{\underset{k\geq2}{\sum}a_{k}}}=2\underset{2}{\underbrace{\underset{k\geq2}{\sum}a_{k-1}x^{k}}}+5\underset{3}{\underbrace{\underset{k\geq2}{\sum}a_{k-2}x^{k}}}\\
\end{align*}

***Working on 1***

\begin{align*}
\underset{k\geq2}{\sum}a_{k} & =\underset{k\geq0}{\sum}a_{k}-a_{1}x-a_{0}=f(x)-x\\
\end{align*}

***Working on 2***
\begin{align*}
\underset{k\geq2}{\sum}a_{k-1}x^{k} & =x\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}a_{k}x^{k}=x\left(\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}a_{k}x^{k}-a_{0}\right)=xf\left(x\right)\\
\end{align*}
***Working on 3***

\begin{align*}
\underset{k\geq2}{\sum}a_{k-2}x^{k} & =x^{2}\left(\underset{k\geq0}{\sum}a_{k}x^{k}\right)=x^{2}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)\\
\end{align*}
***Putting it back together***

\begin{align*}
f\left(x\right)-x & =2\left[x\left(f\left(x\right)\right)\right]-5x^{2}f\left(x\right)\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
 & \therefore f\left(x\right)=\frac{x}{1-2x+5x^{2}}\\
\end{align*}

From here, I am not too sure of where to go as I can see that the denominator is irriducible over the real numbers and I have the feeling that partial fractions with complex values is going to get a bit nasty rather quickly. Hence my believe that I have messed something up along the line and turning to you guys for a hand.

Thank you and kindest regards!

Comment: according to https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a_n+%3D+2a_%7Bn-1%7D+-+5a_%7Bn-2%7D, the final solution will involve complex numbers, so sometimes you gotta get your hands dirty. Btw, the "Working on 1" should be $f(x) - x - 1$ and "Working on 2" should be $x(f(x) - 1)$ since $a_0 = 1$.

Comment: Aaah yes. I seem to have entered the question text wrong. I'll quickly edit that as a0=0 in the text. Don't know why I've got it as 1!!

Answer (score 2):

$$
    \dfrac{x}{1 - 2x + 5x^2} = \left(\dfrac{1}{2} - \dfrac{1}{4}i\right)\dfrac{1}{5x - 1 - 2i} + \left(\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{4}i\right)\dfrac{1}{5x - 1 + 2i}
$$

The first fraction can be expressed as:
$$
      \dfrac{1}{5x - 1 - 2i} = -\dfrac{1 - 2i}{5}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (1 - 2i)^n x^n
$$
Similarly for the second fraction:
$$
      \dfrac{1}{5x - 1 + 2i} = -\dfrac{1 + 2i}{5}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (1 + 2i)^n x^n
$$

Thus,
$$
     \dfrac{x}{1 - 2x + 5x^2} = \dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty x^n i[(1-2i)^n - (1 + 2i)^n]
$$

which means
$$
    a_n = \dfrac{1}{4}i[(1 - 2i)^n - (1 + 2i)^n]
$$

By the De Moivre's formula,
$$
    a_n = \dfrac{5^{n/2}}{2}\sin(n \alpha) \ \forall n \ge 0
$$

where $\alpha$ is the angle such that
$$
    \cos\alpha = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, \sin \alpha = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}}
$$